# Set same design for EditText as in TextView in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am using a LinearLayout with one EditText and two TextViews.
The design of the Edit text is very unique. it has an underline and the text is somewhere in the middle of the element hovering above the groundline.

I would like to have an EditText that looks like an TextView from a design perspective. How would I get that?

thanks

Comment: than you have to create a custom edittext with the help of drawble

Comment: android:background="@android:color/transparent" in edittext to remove the bottom bar which appears. 
To align the text, and to customise the font color, family and size refer here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_edittext_control.htm

Comment: "I would like to have an EditText that looks like an TextView from a design perspective." What you want to do exactly, remove the underline of the `EditText`? Remove the cursor of the `EditText`? Is that possible that you post a picture tell us what you want?